# MySQL innacurate calculation with average and datetime

Tags: mysql, average, timestampdiff

I'm having problems with time average calculations. I have a table with a lot of records, the table structure is user id, begin and end time of work (if you want, you can [download the table script here](https://cielotico.com/test.sql)) and I need to get the effective working time average of each user, so I go like this for the average:

```
select iduser, sec_to_time(avg(timestampdiff(second, begin, end))) 
from test 
group by iduser;
```

So far so good, it returns:

```
USER1 00:25:55.9327
USER2 05:47:44.8713
USER3 03:13:43.4724
```

However, the problem is when I try to calculate the average of all users (no grouping):

```
select sec_to_time(avg(timestampdiff(second,begin, end))),avg(timestampdiff(second,begin, end))
from test;
```

it returns '03:26:18.9014', but according to my calculations, it should return 03:09:07.333. I checked with constant values and excel test

```
select sec_to_time((time_to_sec("00:25:55.9327")+time_to_sec("05:47:44.8713")+time_to_sec("3:13:43.4724"))/3);
```

So far I don't understand why it's returning '03:26:18.9014', it's innacurate according to the other calculations. Do anybody have an idea why is this happening?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example of the problem, as tabular text in the question, so one can investigate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it's statistic math basics, I can't get the same result if there are different number of records in the groups, each user would have to have the same number of records

Answer (score 0):

If you run this query

```
select  count(iduser) as cnt,
    sum(timestampdiff(SECOND, `begin`, `end`)) as tot,
    avg(timestampdiff(SECOND, `begin`, `end`)) as aver,
    sec_to_time(avg(timestampdiff(SECOND, `begin`, `end`))) as tim
from test ;
```

RESULT

```
cnt     tot         aver        tim
2903    35935951    12378.9015  03:26:18.9014
```

You get all the parts so that you can do your own calculations and it appears correct